# search stops after the first match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `attribute_set_id` indexed at two different places in each id. I want to search and get results from both the places(actually I want from the second one). What is happening now, is that the following query searches only for the first instance of "attribute_set_id" and when does not find the match, returns zero.
`{"query":{terms:{attribute_set_id:["Bags"]}}}'`

Comment: It would be great if you could post a curl-based reproduction of this problem. Elasticsearch is quite complex product and it's somewhat difficult to deduce what went wrong from this description.

Comment: When I use the command  `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/index/id/_search?pretty=true -d '{"query":{terms:{attribute_set_id:["Bags"]}}}' ` 
I dont get any results. But in the indexed page, I have two occurrences of `attribute_set_id`,one `attribute_set_id:"91"` and other `attribute_set_id:"Bags"`

Comment: Does '{"query":{terms:{attribute_set_id:["bags"]}}}' return you any results?

Comment: No this is the problem it returns no results. Whereas `'{"query":{terms:{attribute_set_id:["91"]}}}' ` returns proper result

Comment: What I feel the problem is that the elasticsearch stops the search as soon as it finds the first match to term `attribute_set_id` and returns the results.

Comment: Did you run it with "bags" in lower case exactly as in my comment? Could you post mapping for this index?

Comment: its a huge mapping....as I mentioned the problem is that only. Elasticsearch stops  as it finds the first match. I got the same difficulty somewhere else also. Is there any way to tell elasticsearch that I want all possible matches.

Comment: both of them are actually mapped as strings only...

Comment: It is difficult to help you based on limited amount of information that you've provided. You can simplify the job for people who are trying to help you by providing them with a simple reproduction of your issue using curl. I understand that your mapping might be huge, but it's in your best interest to make an effort and remove non-relevant parts of the mapping before posting it. If you will check past elasticsearch questions with curl reproductions, you will find that they are typically answered within a few hours. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/help/ for more details.

Comment: okay i will create a sample small example

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876548/not-getting-all-the-results