# Not getting all the results

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my question related to my previous question that I asked       [search stops after the first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783994/search-stops-after-the-first-match#comment14130234_10783994)

Here I am giving you the mapping.

```
{
    "copy_order_snapshot": {
        "properties": {
            "line_item_info": {
                "dynamic": "true",
                "properties": {
                    "m_product_details": {
                        "dynamic": "true",
                        "properties": {
                            "accessories_colour": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "status": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "other_details": {
                        "dynamic": "true",
                        "properties": {
                            "accessories_material_type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                            "status": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "product_details": {
                        "dynamic": "true",
                        "properties": {
                            "accessories_colour": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "status": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "order_data": {
                "dynamic": "true",
                "properties": {
                    "state": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my previous question I was talking about `attribute_set_id` , here the same case is with `status`. The `order_details->status is "enabled"` while the other status are as `"1" and "canceled"`. When I search for

```
{
    "query":{
        "term":{
            "status":"enabled"
         }
    }
}
```

I get the result

but if I search for

```
{
    "query":{
        "term":{
            "status":"1"
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "query":{
        "term":{
            "status":"canceled"
        }
    }
}
```

I get no results.

Please help.

Comment: Vipul, based on the information that you have provided, one can come up with the following script in attempt to demonstrate the issue: https://gist.github.com/2868005 Unfortunately, this script works just fine. So, there must be something still missing in your description of the problem. Could you modify this script to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: The point is `status:"1"` or `status:"enabled"` or `status:"canceled" are not in three different ids but all occur in the same id. For a single id, I have all these three terms under `order_details` , `order_data` and `product_details`.

Comment: Vipul, I have updated https://gist.github.com/2868005 to contain an example of repro for your question.

Comment: Thanks for uploading it on github...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of ambiguous field name "status". During query processing, elasticsearch resolves the field name "status" into the first fully qualified field name that it matches. When I ran it on my machine, it got resolved into line_item_info.other_details.status.

```
$ curl "localhost:9200/test-orders/_validate/query?q=status:blah&explain=true&pretty=true"
{
  "valid" : true,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "explanations" : [ {
    "index" : "test-orders",
    "valid" : true,
    "explanation" : "line_item_info.other_details.status:blah"
  } ]
}
```

If you want your query to match all status fields, you might need to use fully qualified names (such as `line_item_info.other_details.status`, `line_item_info.m_product_details.status`, etc.) and combine them using [Dis Max](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/dis-max-query.html) or [Bool Queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html).

For example:

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/test-orders/copy_order_snapshot/_search -d '{
    "query":{
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
                {
                    "term" : { "line_item_info.m_product_details.status" : "1" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "line_item_info.other_details.status" : "enabled" }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```